# How to make video and image to scale proportionally

Tags: html, css

I have a site with background where video on the top and straight under the video there is an image that appears like an extension of the video and have to coincide with it at screens above 1000px.

In the middle of the video i have an object(planet) an i want the video behavior like `object-fit: cover` to have the planet place always in the middle. I put `object-fit: cover` on video and on image tag but when the width of screen achives the original width of video and img (1920px) video begin to overlay the image.

What should i do to make them scale  proportionally on screens more then 1920?

And is there any way to do this using background-image instead of img tag?

[Link to my code](http://codepen.io/foxer1/pen/XKNaRe/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.